# ios Resizing images for thumbs - Blurry although high interpolation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimage, image-resizing

I have written a category on `UIImage` to resize images like the iphone photos app.

Although the Interpolation is set to high, the image does not really look like the one in the photos app. Instead it looks `unsharp` or `blurry`.

Here is what I did:

```
    - (UIImage *)resizeImageProportionallyIntoNewSize:(CGSize)newSize;
    {
    CGFloat scaleWidth = 1.0f;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = 1.0f;

    NSLog(@"Origin Size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.size));

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(self.size, newSize) == NO) {

        //calculate "the longer side"
        if(self.size.width > self.size.height) {
            scaleWidth = self.size.width / self.size.height;
        } else {
            scaleHeight = self.size.height / self.size.width;
        }
    }    

    // now draw the new image in a context with scaling proportionally
    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    //now we create a context in newSize and draw the image out of the bounds of the context to get
    //an proportionally scaled image by cutting of the image overlay
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00) {
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 2.0);
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    //Center image point so that on each egde is a little cutoff
    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = (int) newSize.width * scaleWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = (int) newSize.height * scaleHeight;
    thumbnailRect.origin.x = (int) (newSize.width - thumbnailRect.size.width) * 0.5;
    thumbnailRect.origin.y = (int) (newSize.height - thumbnailRect.size.height) * 0.5;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}
```

BTW: There is no difference on using high interpolation or not. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please, do not use "[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00". It may not work as you want it to.

Comment: I'd suggest using a higher res image, or a vector format.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII why should I use a higher res image? I am scaling it DOWN! The res should be okay, the original image is 8 times bigger - did you read the question?

Comment: @AlexanderBabaev what should I use instead?

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]); is usually ok. And you always can use fabs([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale], 2) < 0.001 (some small number). You also can use (int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2, for example.

Comment: The line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, 2.0);` has no effect because you the line `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);` is always executed. You probably want to add an `else` to your `if`.

Comment: If your thumbnail has an odd height or width and you display it centered in a UIImageView, then it will become blurry because it's not properly aligned to the pixels (it has an offset of 0.5 pixels).

Comment: @Codo Oh my God!!!! That fixed it :) I forgot the else. Can't be true -.- Great thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to make a thumbnail is to ask the system to do it for you, using the Image I/O Framework. The only trick is that since you're using a CGImage you must take account of the screen resolution:

```
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWith... // whatever
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
CGFloat w = // maximum size, multiplied by the scale
NSDictionary* d = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat,
     (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
     (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways,
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)w], kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize,
     nil];
CGImageRef imref = 
    CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)d);
UIImage* im = 
    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
CFRelease(imref); CFRelease(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is unsharp / blurry, you should try to turn off anti-aliasing by:

```
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
```

hope this helps.